# Calculate one time and recurring charges associated with each of the items on a form

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to calculate one time and recurring charges associated with each of the items on [my Cognito form](https://www.cognitoforms.com/MarketMyHolisticPractice/WebsiteAndMarketingServicesForm).

Some are yes/no and some are choices. I want to associate charges with choices, but I can't figure out the syntax.

Help please?

These don't work:

> A value of type Double cannot be converted to type Yes/No at character 77
>
> =if(SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("10.70")) ? 10.70: 0 +if(SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("17.70")) ? 17.70: 0 +if(SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("27.70")) ? 27.70: 0 +if(SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("32.70")) ? 32.70: 0 +if(SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("37.70")) ? 37.70: 0
>
> No field 'Choice' exists in 'WebsiteAndMarketingServicesForm' at character 0
>
> =Choice.Count(it = "One newsletter with 6 articles, $10.70 per month.") * 10.70 + Choice.Count(it = "Two newsletters (every other week) with 3 articles, $17.70 each month.") * 17.70 + Choice.Count(it = "Three newsletters (every 9-10 days) with 2 articles, $22.70 each month.") * 22.70  + Choice.Count(it = "Four newsletters (one per week) with 1-2 articles, $27.70 each month.") * 27.70 + Choice.Count(it = "Five newsletters (one every 5-6 days) with 1-2 articles, $32.70 each month.") * 32.70 + Choice.Count(it = "Six newsletters (one every 4-5 days) with 1 article, $37.70 each month") * 37.70

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to assign/calculate prices for choice and yes/no fields in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

1. Select `Assign Prices` under field settings and enter prices for each choice or a single price for Yes/No fields.  This assigned price will be available in calculations as FieldName_Amount.
2. Create a `Price` or `Calculation - Currency` field and write a calculation using `if` - `then` logic, similar to what you included in your question.

Here is the correct syntax in your case:

```
=    if SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("10.70") then 10.70
else if SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("17.70") then 17.70
else if SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("27.70") then 27.70
else if SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("32.70") then 32.70
else if SendMedicineTalkNewslettersToYourNewsletterList.Contains("37.70") then 37.70
else 0
```

Obviously the Assign Prices option is easier, but custom calculations can give you more control.

Comment: Because there are one time and recurring charges, I will use the calculation - currency

Comment: but the second if doesn't work
= if MembershipSuite then 97 else 0
+ if Webstore then 97 else 0

What needs to change?

Comment: @Sam I'll be honest, I have no clue what the second calculation is attempting to do, so was unable to clean this up.  If you are trying to use an if - then - else in a calculation, you may need to use () around it to keep things straight.  Also, the error message you received indicates that there is not a field named Choice on your form in the section your calculation is in.

Comment: Your email corrected it! All set, thanks.
= (if MembershipSuite then 97 else 0)
+ (if Webstore then 97 else 0)
+ (if Webmailyouyouremailcom then 97 else 0)
+ (if NewsletterTemplateCreation then 47 else 0)
+ (if SocialMediaSiteSetup then 47 else 0)